# Firebase Fastlane build fails with Requested entity was not found

Tags: firebase, flutter, fastlane

I Enabled App Distribution in firebase project console, still i'm getting this error.Please help.

Fastlane version:fastlane 2.178.0
fastlane-plugin-firebase_app_distribution | 0.2.5

```
D, [2021-03-19T11:38:43.671717 #5689] DEBUG -- request: GET https://firebaseappdistribution.googleapis.com/v1alpha/apps/1:XXXXXXXX:android:cdeXXXXXXX30aD, [2021-03-19T11:38:45.266721 #5689] DEBUG -- response: Status 404D, [2021-0319T11:38:45.266794 #5689] DEBUG -- response: {"error": {
"code": 404,
"message": "Requested entity was not found.",
"status": "NOT_FOUND"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry the issue is in my App ID, By mistake i have place wrong app id.After correction issue resolved.